# Projecting all the points from the csv file at (0,0) in a map

Tags: geotools

I am trying to plot some points on a map using the GeoTools tutorial (http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html).
Unexpectedly all the points given in the .csv file are being plotted at (0,0). I don't why is it happening.

Please help me resolve this issue.

I am using Maven and using the same code given in the Tutorial in the above mentioned URL.

Comment: what is in your csv file?

Comment: Csv is an excel and the csv file contains the lat/long pairs which are to be displayed on the map. Here my error is all different lat/long pairs are shown at a single point

Comment: I was interested in the values of some of the points